# Clear Android activity stack and start activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this question has been answered in another posts also. But it doesn't solve my issue.

I have `3 screens: A,B and Home`. App starts with A, then goes to B and then to Home page. But I want to delete activities A and B when it reaches Home activity, so that when `back is pressed app exits`.

I tried:

1. `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. It works fine when back is pressed. App quits. But if I again open the app from background, it starts with screen B.
2. `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.` This works exactly as I want. But when Home activity starts, there is a sudden glitch in the screen and it is not smooth.

Comment: you can finish that activity a and b on home activity load or can handle back press

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear all the activities on top of home.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            i2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
finish(); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK results in a glitch and transition is not smooth

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also, for your splashScreen(A) you can set nohistory=true in AndroidMenifest.xml, and goto Activity(B), and when you are going on Activity Home from Activity(B) finish activity(B) than goto Home activity.
so both of your previous activities will not store in stack.

And on Activity B override onBackPresh() method but remove super.backpresh() in side it. and start your activity A with finish this current activity, it will work.

Comment: In your solution, if I press back button from B it won't go back to A.

Comment: in general we are not displaying slash screen again if once we display it, its for one time only.

Comment: They both are login screens. So going back is necessary in my context.

Comment: try with first one and on activity B override backrest() and in that start activity A with finish activity B. but be sure remove super.backpresh() inside onBackPresh()